# problemas con un RecyclerView?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, recyclerview, checkbox

tengo un recyclerview, tengo un checkbox en los objetos de la vista que añado al recyclerview, cuando selecciono un objeto y recorro el recycler me aparecen varios objetos seleccionados, que puede ser este detalle alquien le pasa lo mismo, dejo codigo, no es nada fuera de lo normal

```
public class AV_MT extends RecyclerView.Adapter<IVH_mt> {

    private List<CM_CC_MT> l_cats;
    Context mContext;

    public AV_MT(Context context, List<CM_CC_MT> lvistaimg) {
        this.l_cats = lvistaimg;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(IVH_mt itemViewHolder, int i) {
        final CM_CC_MT model = l_mt.get(i);
        itemViewHolder.bind(model);
    }

    @Override
    public IVH_mt onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cv_item_mt, viewGroup, false);
        return new IVH_mt(view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return l_mt.size();
    }

    public void setFilter(List<CM_CC_MT> pmodel) {
        l_cats = new ArrayList<>();
        l_cats.addAll(pmodel);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}

public class IVH_mt extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tv_p1, tv_p2, tv_p3, tv_p4;
    CardView cv_item_mt;
    CheckBox cb_item;

    Boolean b_var = false;

    public IVH_mt(View iView) {
        super(iView);

        itemView.setClickable(true);

        tv_p1 = iView.findViewById(R.id.tv_p1);
        tv_p2 = iView.findViewById(R.id.tv_p2);
        tv_p3 = iView.findViewById(R.id.tv_p3);
        tv_p4 = iView.findViewById(R.id.tv_p4);
        cb_item = iView.findViewById(R.id.cb_item);
        cv_item_mt = iView.findViewById(R.id.cv_item_mt);

    }

    public void bind(final CM_CC_MT cm_cat) {

        tv_p1.setText(cm_cat.Muestra);
        tv_p2.setText(cm_cat.Id_calidad);
        tv_p3.setText(cm_cat.Venta);
        tv_p4.setText(cm_cat.Nombre_CP);

        cv_botones.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        final DBA_CC_MuestrasRelacionadas dba_mtr = new DBA_CC_MuestrasRelacionadas(getActivity());
        dba_mtr.Abre();

        final CM_CC_MuetrasRelacionada cm_mtr = new CM_CC_MuetrasRelacionada();

        cm_mtr.setCN_mov_l(gv_cc.getCn_mov_l());
        cm_mtr.setMT_mov(cm_cat.getMT_mov());
        cm_mtr.setMuestra(cm_cat.getMuestra());


        cb_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String testo = null;


                if(cb_item.isChecked()){
                    dba_mtr.addMTRel(cm_mtr);

                }else{
                    dba_mtr.delMTRel(gv_cc.getCn_mov_l(), cm_cat.getMT_mov());                  
                }
            }
        });

        cb_item.setChecked(b_var);

        dba_mtr.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: llevas algo de tiempo en el sitio, te sugerimos nuevamente revisar [ask], aportar detalles e información a tu pregunta, lo que comentas es "sencillo" de corregir pero no sabemos que realizas en el adapter, saludos.

Comment: ok ingreso codigo...

Comment: El objeto CM_CC_MT  no tiene una propiedad para definir si esta checked ?

Comment: no.... suguieres que agregue una propiedad booleana para que almacene el valor del checkbox???

Answer (score 0):

Como te sugería, la mejor opción es agregar otra propiedad a tu objeto `CM_CC_MT` (generar su getter/setter) la cual defina si el elemento se encuentra seleccionado o no.

Usa el método `onBindViewHolder()` para obtener la posición del elemento y por lo tanto el objeto del cual se obtendrán las propiedades y envíalo a tu método `bind()`

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(IVH_mt itemViewHolder, int position) {
     //   final CM_CC_MT model = l_mt.get(i);
        itemViewHolder.bind(position);
    }
```

Suponiendo que tus métodos para obtener y definir la propiedad seleccionada son getChecked() y setChecked(...) en tu método bind() obtiene el valor del checkbox:

```
l_cats.get(position).getChecked()
```

o definirlo

```
l_cats.get(position).setChecked(<"valor true o false">)
```

Este sería un ejemplo de acuerdo a tu código:

```
    public void bind(int position) {
        ...
        ... 
        cb_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String testo = null;


                if(cb_item.isChecked()){
                    dba_mtr.addMTRel(cm_mtr);

                    //*Seleccionado
                    l_cats.get(position).setChecked(true);                       

                }else{
                    dba_mtr.delMTRel(gv_cc.getCn_mov_l(), cm_cat.getMT_mov());                  

                    //*NO Seleccionado
                    l_cats.get(position).setChecked(false);

                }
            }
        });

        //cb_item.setChecked(b_var);

        //*Obtiene valor definido en objeto
        cb_item.setChecked(l_cats.get(position).getChecked());

        dba_mtr.close();

    }
```